# callback afterFind

Tags: cakephp

Olá, ainda continuo sem consegui usar o afterFind, mesmo seguindo alguns posts na net. Me ajudem no controller e model, por favor. Uso o beforeSave, mas não consigo usar o afterFind.

Já coloquei return false ou true no método do controller, mas não adiantou.

Alguém tem algum código funcional com afterFind para me enviar?

controller Despesas

http://www.hastebin.com/uwawofupik.coffee

AppModel

http://www.hastebin.com/tafewekayo.php

Model Despesa

http://www.hastebin.com/bunipehuza.php

Comment: Já tentou da um `exit()` no `afterFind()` para ver se esta passando por ali?

Comment: @Jeferson Assis o exite seria no final do método? E seria assim: exite(); ?

Comment: Eu analisei melhor o seu código, você pode testar a resposta abaixo

Comment: você alterou completamente a sua pergunta, é aconselhável a criar uma nova pergunta quando o problema é diferente do citado nesta.
Volte a pergunta anterior e crie uma nova para que eu possa te ajudar.

Comment: Olá André, recomendo seguir a orientação do Jeferson e separar suas dúvidas em tópicos diferentes e não alterar o contexto da sua pergunta principalmente em casos em que já lhe responderam ela. Se a sua outra dúvida for relacionada a essa aqui você pode linká-la para dar mais contexto. Aproveite e faça um [tour] para conhecer melhor o funcionamento da comunidade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analisando seu código vi que você utilizar o método `query()` da model.

```
$despesas=$this->Despesa->query("select * from despesas where data_despesa like '%$this->dataDespesa%'");
```

Quando você utiliza uma query customizada, ela não passa automaticamente para o `afterFind()`

Você pode fazer a chamada dele em sequência:

```
$despesas = $this->Despesa->afterFind($this->Despesa->query("select * from despesas where data_despesa like '%$this->dataDespesa%'"));
```

Como sua consulta é simples não tem necessidade de fazer uma consulta customizada

Basta utilizar o método `find()`

```
$despesas = $this->Despesa->find('all', array(
    'conditions'=>array(
        'data_despesa like'=>"%{$this->dataDespesa}%"
    )
));
```

Assim ele passará automaticamente por todos os callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Já resolvi. O problema é que eu estava usando os mesmos métodos para formatar data e o valor monetário do beforeSave. O beforeSave substitui o "/" por "-" e coloca no formato y, m, d. E substitui "," por "." no valor monetário.

Para exibir na view, precisava fazer o contrário: colocar a data no formato d, m, y e substituir "-" por "/". E no valor monetário, substituir "." por ",".

AppModel

http://hastebin.com/amabarotey.php

Model Despesa

http://hastebin.com/ipuyajexux.coffee

controller Despesas

http://hastebin.com/yihuwafiba.coffee